# is there way to validate wrong mail-domains like gmail.net?

Tags: java

i was looking for the ways to validate domain, i couldn't.

Yap, i can validate of mail form from regex lib. 
But if there is a correct form not right domain, how can i make it right?

For Example, 
"test@gmail.net"

- Of course i have a whiteList for this task. ( gmail.com etc.)
  then, if request parameters are not same with it, i make it right.
  test@gmail.net => form check => and then 'gmail.net > gmail.com'

I expect some code to make domains sure to send mail.

```
//main
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String email = "test@gmail.net"; 
    boolean isNormal = checkEmail(email); 

    if (isNormal == true) {
        // I don't see how can make it.
        // Should i hardcode about wrong domain like gmail.net? 
        // So on, i have to wirte down gmail.net, gmail.us.kr.....like it?

    }
}

// format validate
public boolean checkEmail(String email) {
    String regex = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@(?:\\w+\\.)+\\w+$";   
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
    boolean isNormal = m.matches(); 
    return isNormal;
}
```

Comment: What if someone buys gmail.net?

Comment: l'm so sorry, i deceided to make a list of some domains to be correted already, and i'will make sure just them.

Comment: but is anyone who have idea about it, please give me your hand please!! <3

Comment: What is your definition of a 'wrong domain'? It sounds like you will need to provide some sort of black/white list.

Comment: @ achAmháin thanks, but  the whiteList is ruled by  my corp, so i can't assume the situation.

Comment: You can query  port 25 for specific domain, if port is open, email appears to be valid

Comment: You can use official Java Email adress Validtor. `InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
      emailAddr.validate();` if this throws `AddressException` then the adress is not valid.

Comment: You could look up the domain name using a DNS client - but that's not going to be trivial unless someone wrote a library. You need to follow the rules of the RFCs (the standards)  for emails to do this.

Comment: @procrastinator `InternetAddress.validate()` considers "user@[10.9.8.7]" and "user@localhost" as valid email addresses... I think OP doesn't want these to be evaluated as valid emails

Comment: thanks to everyone, finall i found how i can validate mail-domain. i just asked to my boss what we use domain in programm generally, so i made a array for this. so i use operators in javascript that wall the others up. And i thought of your ideas, InternetAddress in JAVA, RFC, etc. thank you really !!!!!!  if i can, i would help someone like me. lastly,  thanks, the guy who formatted my codes